# TabNavigator unable to load?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I've created a new project using Expo XDE and trying to learn `React-Navigation`. I've modified `App.js` as below

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: { screen: AuthScreen }
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, `MainNavigator` component should refer to `const MainNavigator` and render 2 tabs but there isn't any tabs being loaded into simulator. May I know which part went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things...

The TabNavigation doesn't seem to play well being the child of a view...which makes sense since it's supposed to handle that within the screens. Removing the parent `<View>` fixes that. Deal with styling the view within the screens.

I'd also recommend not defining the `MainNavigator` variable inside the render method. While it's not app breaking, it's not the best practice and might have some unforeseen consequences when your app gets larger.

Final code:

```
import React from 'react';
// import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';

const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
  welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
  auth: { screen: AuthScreen }
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MainNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```